# Converting Postgre to Bigquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-bigquery, subquery

I am having a trouble with a conversion from Postgre to Bigquery query.

Please, how could this query work on bigquery ? I need to subselect a table and bring the last register

```
(select g.fase__c
from operacoes.salesforce_gest_o_do_canal_c_full g
where g.n_de_indentifica_o_do_parceiro__c = a.n_de_indentifica_o_do_parceiro__c
order by g.data_do_credenciamento__c limit 1)  as fase_jornada

from operacoes.salesforce_account_full
```

If I try to execute, Bigquery returns an error I should apply a join, If I apply the join, the order by doesn´t work

Thanks!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Queries do not usually start with an open parentheses and your code would generate na error in either database.

Comment: I am having this error message: Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN.

Comment: Actually, this is the subquery, the query itself starts with a select in salesforce_account full. I am looking for subquery a table based on Id of other table, such this subquery produce n results I need to order by date and query just the last one

Answer (score 0):

A correlated subquery (which is a subquery that references a table of an outer query), if executed "as is", would need to compute the subquery for each row of the results of the outer query, which would not be very efficient.

In order to optimize this, BigQuery first transforms (decorrelates) the query into one that is functionally equivalent to the correlated one but without any correlations between queries and subqueries. Different decorrelation processes are needed for different use cases and they can be quite complex and difficult to implement and properly test.

BigQuery is implementing decorrelation strategies to make a variety of [correlated subqueries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#correlated_subqueries) possible, however decorrelation for the `LIMIT` clause has not been implemented.

A workaround would be to use [ARRAY_AGG](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#array_agg) instead of a subquery. In your case, I believe the following query would do the work:

```
SELECT
  ARRAY_AGG(g.fase__c
    ORDER BY g.data_do_credenciamento__c
    LIMIT 1) AS fase_jornada
FROM
  operacoes.salesforce_account_full a
JOIN
  operacoes.salesforce_gest_o_do_canal_c_full g
ON
  g.n_de_indentifica_o_do_parceiro__c = a.n_de_indentifica_o_do_parceiro__c
GROUP BY
  g.n_de_indentifica_o_do_parceiro__c
```

Take into account that I have guessed some details since the whole context for the subquery was not provided, so you may need to make some changes to it.

Please let me know if anything was not clear!